# Why is my custom JSONEncoder.default() ignoring booleans?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoder

I want to convert a dictionary to a JSON string with boolean `True` values translated to the number `1` and boolean `False` values translated to the number `0`. I'm using a `JSONEncoder` subclass, but it seems to ignore booleans ...

```
import json

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bool):
            return 1 if obj else 0
    return super().default(obj)

data = { 'key-a' : 'a', 'key-true' : True, 'key-false' : False }

jsondata = json.dumps(data, cls=MyEncoder)

print(jsondata)
```

I want this to be the result:

```
{"key-true": 1, "key-a": "a", "key-false": 0}
```

However, this is what I get:

```
{"key-true": true, "key-a": "a", "key-false": false}
```

I know I can programatically modify the data before passing it to `json.dumps`, but is there any way I can obtain my desired result via a `JSONEncoder` subclass?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `default()` method of `JSONEncoder` subclasses is called only when the encoder encounters an object it doesn't otherwise know how to serialize.

Unfortunately, the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) doesn't make this very clear. It's mentioned, but in the "keyword arguments" section for the class constructor, rather than in the documentation for the method:

> If specified, *default* should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON encodable version of the object or raise a `TypeError`. If not specified, `TypeError` is raised.

This behaviour can easily be verified:

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bool):
            print('got bool')
            return 1 if obj else 0
        if isinstance(obj, Foo):
            print('got Foo')
            return {'__Foo__': id(obj)}
        print('got unknown')
        return super().default(obj)
```

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> s = json.dumps({'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': Foo()}, cls=MyEncoder)
got Foo
>>> s
'{"a": false, "c": {"__Foo__": 140636444256856}, "b": true}'
```

`JSONEncoder` isn't designed to easily allow overriding the serialization of objects it already knows how to serialize (which is a good thing: the whole point of standards like JSON is that they're, well, *standard*) … so if you really want to encode booleans as though they were integers, the easiest way to do so is probably to preprocess data as suggested in your question.