# JSONEncoder is not being called

Tags: python, json

I am trying to encode JSON with `json.JSONEncoder` with another pattern by overriding the `default` method:

```
class X(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return ["ok"]

json.dumps(self, cls=X)
```

But the default method is not being called... I saw a few examples who looks like this, but I can't figure out what is missing?

currently, I get my json as `{"status": "Fail"}`

Note: followed this **[link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html)**.

I am using python 3.6
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. my object was inherited from `dict`, while `default` method is not being called on object like `dict` and `list`

Answer (score 1):

Having the same kind of problem, I found the complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46205398/12199445

As mentioned is earlier, if the standard `JSONEncoder` is able to encode the value, the `default` method is not called.